# PostCSS stylelint cannot set `comment-no-empty`?

Tags: node.js, stylelint

PostCSS stylelint cannot set `comment-no-empty`?

In `.stylelintrc.json` I have:

```json
{
  "extends": "stylelint-config-recommended-scss",
}
```

When I run this, I get an `Unexpected empty comment` error that I want disabled.

However, `stylelint-config-recommended-scss.js` already has this rule disabled:

```js
rules: {
  'annotation-no-unknown': null,
  'at-rule-no-unknown': null,
  'comment-no-empty': null,
}
```

And adding it to `.stylelintrc.json` doesn't work either.

```json
{
  "extends": "stylelint-config-recommended-scss",
  "rules": {
    "comment-no-empty": null
  }
}
```

Am I missing something? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `stylelint-config-recommended-scss` config *replaces* the built-in `comment-no-empty` rule with its own `scss/comment-no-empty` one.

The `scss/comment-no-empty` can detect both `//` and `/* */` empty comments.

To disable the rule, you can turn it off in your config:

```json
{
  "extends": "stylelint-config-recommended-scss",
  "rules": {
    "scss/comment-no-empty": null
  }
}
```

Note that the rule is prefixed with `scss`, the name of the SCSS plugin.

(In your config, you're trying to turn off the already turned-off built-in rule.)